# Actionscript 2.0 scoring system

Tags: actionscript-2, scoring

I'm new to flash and I need to make a scoring system where in when you click on a symbol (button) in the stage it will add to the score textbox. I have this simple code:

`on(release) {
    _root.points++;
    _root.score.text = _root.points; 
}`

that I put on the button and it works fine, the problem is when I click on another button on the stage the score textbox displays the word NAN instead of increasing by one.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: NaN stands for "Not a Number". It means you've tried to set "points" to a value that is a string type (for example, the word "score"). What code is on the other button?

Comment: ah thanks for the answer, i've already solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code... make sure you have the same code in the other buttons... perhaps you spelled a variables wrong when you were setting the .text equal to _root.points; (did you forget to pluralize it? I do that alot haha)